# Timeout executing duration instead of command

Tags: bash, docker, sh

I have a function within a bash script that is executing the following:

```
get_repo_master_hash() {
    timeout 60 bash -c "git ls-remote $REPOURL | grep refs/heads/master | cut -f 1"
}
```

But when this is executed within my script I receive the following:

```
timeout: can't execute '60': No such file or directory
```

Why is it executing the duration instead of my command?

This script is being executed within a docker container that is using alpine/git:1.0.4 as the image.

Comment: Add output of `type timeout` and information about the operating system used to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus the output of `type timeout` is `timeout is /usr/bin/timeout`. Above in the original question I've updated it with what the command is running on OS-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Docker `alpine:3.6` container I get

```
$timeout --help
Usage: timeout [-t SECS] [-s SIG] PROG ARGS
```

So you should do `timeout -t 60` instead.